# Basic + Slice + Map Type Compatible Generics?

Tags: go, generics

Is there a way to create a generic function that can adjust its operation when passed a map or a slice type vs a basic type?

## Goal

Create a slice reading function generator with a flexible return type:

```golang
func ValueReader[T <probably something fancy>](i int) func ([]ProtoConvertable) T {
    return func (row []ProtoConvertable) T {
        return ...
    }
}

row := []ProtoConvertable{
    &Data[int]{Value: 333},
    &ListData{Values: []ProtoConvertable{
        &Data[string]{Value: "hello"},
        &Data[string]{Value: "world"},
    }},
    &MapData{Values: map[ProtoConvertable]ProtoConvertable{
        &Data[int]{Value: 22}: &Data[string]{Value: "world"},
        &Data[int]{Value: 11}: &Data[string]{Value: "hello"},
    }},
}

dataReader := ValueReader[int](0) // A function that converts the first element to an int
listDataReader := ValueReader[[]string](1) // A function that converts the second element to a slice
mapDataReader := ValueReader[map[int]string](2) // A function that converts the third element to a map

data := dataReader(row) // 333
listData := listDataReader(row) // []string{"hello", "world"}
mapData := mapDataReader(row) // map[int]string{11: "hello", 22: "world"}
```

## Types

```golang
type ValueType interface {
    int | string
}

type ProtoConvertable interface {
    ToProto() *pb.GenericMessage
}

type Data[T ValueType] struct {
    Value T
}

func (d *Data) ToProto() *pb.GenericMessage{
    ...
}

type ListData struct {
    Values []ProtoConvertable
}

func (d *ListData) ToProto() *pb.GenericMessage {
    ...
}

type MapData struct {
    Values map[ProtoConvertable]ProtoConvertable
}

func (d *MapData) ToProto() *pb.GenericMessage {
    ...
}
```

## Current Solution

```golang
func ValueReader[T ValueType](i int) func([]ProtoConvertable) T {
    return func(row []ProtoConvertable) T {
        return row[i].(*Data[T]).Value
    }
}

func ListValueReader[T ValueType](i int) func([]ProtoConvertable) []T {
    return func(row []ProtoConvertable) []T {
        vs := row[i].(*ListData).Values
        res := make([]T, len(vs))
        for i, v := range vs {
            res[i] = v.(*Data[T]).Value
        }
        return res
    }
}

func MapValueReader[K ValueType, V ValueType](i int) func([]ProtoConvertable) map[K]V {
    return func(row []ProtoConvertable) map[K]V {
        vs := row[i].(*MapData).Values
        res := make(map[K]V, len(vs))
        for k, v := range vs {
            res[k.(*Data[K]).Value] = v.(*Data[V]).Value
        }
        return res
    }
}

dataReader := ValueReader[int](0)
listDataReader := ListValueReader[string](1)
mapDataReader := MapValueReader[int, string](2)
```

**Note:** all of this code is an untested simplification of a more complicated library. It might need some tweaking to get to actually work.

Comment: That may be the case, but I'm wondering if theres some clever hack I'm just not seeing. I can be a bit flexible on the types as long as they can conform to that interface. The trouble with my current solution is that I couldn't do something like `MapValueReader[map[int][]string](row)`, and I have to make a separate `ListMapValueReader[K CassandraKeyType, V ~[]S, S CassandraType]` function.

Comment: Yes. Sadly, it’s dropping generics and going back to reflection. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<probably something fancy>` doesn't exist.

The main issue is that you want to model a type parameter that matches a base value *and two composite types*, one of which is a map type where you want to capture both `K` and `V`.

Even if it existed, the body of `ValueReader` would be a type-switch on `T` to return each specialized reader function, so your existing solution that involves a small amount of code duplication seems just a better strategy overall.

My advice is to use generics when the operations on the different concrete types of `T` are really identical. You can read more at: https://go.dev/blog/when-generics